# How to clean the Output

Tags: perl

I open a file and print some data on the screen , but I want to clean the screen after I output the data , I use `clear`; in the program but I don't see the effect of clean . It didn't clean .Does there 
any command or function can let me do that?

I want to see the contain of a file only , but not to see some of the previous file on the screen ...

Here is my programs

```
`ls > File_List`;
open List , "<./File_List";
while(eof(List)!=1)
{
        $Each = readline(*List);
        chomp $Each;

        print $Each;
        print "\n";
        `clear`;
        open F , "<./$Each";
        while(eof(F)!=1)
        {
                for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
                {
                        $L = readline(*F);
                        print $L;
                }
                last;
        }
        close(F);
        sleep(3);
        $Each = "";
}
close List;
```

Thanks

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear` isn't working because the control sequence it outputs to clear the screen is being captured and returned to your program instead of being sent to the display.

Try

```
print `clear`
```

or

```
system('clear')
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

Your program uses non-idiomatic Perl. A more natural style would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'exec';

opendir my $dh, "." or die "$0: opendir: $!";

while (defined(my $name = readdir $dh)) {
  if (-T $name) {
    system("clear") == 0 or warn "$0: clear exited " . ($? >> 8);
    print $name, "\n";
    system("head", "-20", $name) == 0 or warn "$0: head exited " . ($? >> 8);

    sleep 3;
  }
}
```

Instead of writing a list of names to another file, read the names directly with [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) and [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html). The `defined` check is necessary in case you have a file named `0`, which Perl considers to be a false value and would terminate the loop prematurely.

You don’t want to print *everything*. The directory entry may be a directory or an executable image or a tarball. The `-T` file test attempts to guess whether the file is a text file.

Invoke the external `clear` command using Perl’s [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Finally, use the external `head` command to print the first 20 lines of each text file.

Comment: Seems a shame to drop `ls` in favour of `opendir`/`readdir` and then shell out just to use `head`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you provided doesn't work because the `clear` command is performed in a sub-shell. I suggest the use of a CPAN module (and multi platform supported): [Term::Screen::Uni](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aScreen%3a%3aUni)

Example:

```
use Term::Screen::Uni;
my $screen = Term::Screen::Uni->new;
$screen->clrscr;
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the existence of a sub-shell. The problem is that the output of `\`clear\`` doesn't go to the display.

Answer (score 0):

Use `system()`, it works.

```
system("ls > File_List");
system("clear;");
```